# My label is not displaying in a GUI prefix expression program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, label, expression

I'm using a GUI for a prefix expression program. The programme itself works fine, but the GUI is a bit problematic. When I run it, the result label doesn't show up. I've tried everything, but I don't know why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PrefixExpression extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField expression;
    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel instruction;
    private JLabel results;
    private final int WIDTH = 310;
    private final int HEIGHT = 175;
    private JButton calculateBtn;

    public PrefixExpression()
    {
        setTitle("Prefix Expression Calculator");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        title = new JLabel("Calculating Prefix Expressions");
        instruction = new JLabel("Please enter your expression");
        expression = new JTextField(10);
        calculateBtn = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateBtn.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(instruction);
        panel.add(expression);
        panel.add(calculateBtn);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrefixExpression main = new PrefixExpression();
    }



    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Stack <Integer> numberStack = new Stack <Integer>();
            Stack <Character> operatorStack = new Stack <Character>();


            String input = expression.getText();

            StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input, " ", false);


            while (strToken.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String i = strToken.nextToken();
                int number;
                char operator;

                try
                {
                    number = Integer.parseInt(i);
                    numberStack.push(number);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    operator = i.charAt(0);
                    operatorStack.push(operator);
                }
            }

            int answer = calculateMethod(numberStack, operatorStack);
            results = new JLabel("Here is your answer: " + answer); 
            panel.add(results);  //This is where the results label is added to panel
     }

        public int calculateMethod(Stack <Integer> numberStack, Stack <Character> operatorStack)
        {
            int result = 0;
            while(! numberStack.empty())
            {
                char operator = (char) operatorStack.pop();
                if (operator == '+')
                    result = addition(numberStack);
                else if (operator == '*')
                    result = multiplication(numberStack);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public int addition(Stack <Integer> numberStack)
        {
            int numb1 = (int) numberStack.pop();
            int numb2 = (int) numberStack.pop();
            int answer = numb1 + numb2;
            return answer;
        }

        public int multiplication(Stack <Integer> numberStack)
        {
            int numb1 = (int) numberStack.pop();
            int numb2 = (int) numberStack.pop();
            int answer = numb1 * numb2;
            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> panel.add(results);  //This is where the results label is added to panel

When you add a component to a visible GUI you need to do:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

This will invoke the layout manager and size the component appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the layout of the JPanel to something other than flow layout, create and add the results JLabel to your panel before the result is calculated. Then you just need to use `results.setText(answer);`, in order to display the result, after you are done, unless you want to have all your results visible in the panel.